# Abrir automaticamente o meu programa c#

Tags: c#

Boas,

Criei um programa para converter uns formatos de ficheiros.
Agora no windows, pus por default, que sempre que eu clicar 2x no ficheiro *.csr abrir o meu programa.
Como faço programaticamente, sempre que o utilizador abrir um ficheiro *.csr, abrir o meu programa, e colocar automaticamente no OpenFileDialog o caminho desse ficheiro?
Obrigado.

Neste momento tenho um botão para abrir ficheiro: CSR ou CNF.
Depois o código que tenho é este:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string arquivoCNF = VariaveisGlobais.cnf;
        string arquivoCSR = VariaveisGlobais.csr;


        ExecutarComandoSSL(arquivoCNF, arquivoCSR);

        textBox3.Text = ("");
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        button4.Enabled = false;
        return;
    }

 //Variáveis
    public static class VariaveisGlobais
    {
        public static string CNF { get; set; }
        public static string CSR { get; set; }
        public static string cnf { get; set; }
        public static string csr { get; set; }
    }
```

O que estou pedindo é:
Se o utilizador NÃO ABRE o programa, mas abre directamente um CSR ou CNF, ele corre esse código.

Comment: No seu programa ou no VisualStudio? Voce criou um programa que le os ficheiros?

Comment: Não entendi @GuilhermeNascimento...

Comment: Voce esta criando um software que lê os arquivos ou você quer configurar o visualstudio? Voce disse "Criei um programa" isto da a entender que voce criou um programa que lê arquivos .csr, entao o seu problema nao e com o visualstudio e sim com o seu programa. Talvez a resposta do resposta do OnoSendai lhe ajude. Mas o que me parece e que voce quer deixar pre selecionado no OpenDialog, no entanto isto nao esta claro ainda.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é isso mesmo amigo. Eu quero que ai abrir o .csr o programa corra o código que eu tenho.
Quando se abre o meu programa tem um botão para abrir o ficheiro CSR e fazer a leitura.
O que eu quero é que a pessoa quando abre um ficheiro CSR (sem o programa) ele abra o programa sozinho e corra o código.

Comment: Então poste o que fez ate agora, por favor leia esta orientação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento editado!

Comment: Não tem como correr o código diretamente, o que vai correr é o código compilado em um aplicativo. Você quer criar um aplicativo que no windows o tal aplicativo fique definido como padrão pra tal extensão?

Answer (score 0):

No Visual Studio:

```
Project Properties > Publish > Options > File Associations
```

Você verá a seguinte interface:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Informe a extensão desejada e o programa associado.

Utilizando a publicação ClickOnce o instalador criará o vínculo entre a extensão e o programa automaticamente.